# Calculation of Two Cells According To Condition

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

i have an asp.net project with coding C#.
I have a table like this;

```
NAME       WORK_TYPE        FM            FM_HOUR
-------------------------------------------------
Mike         IN            -2800                
Mike         OUT            3400             ??
Jane         IN              400
Jane         OUT            -100             ??
```

Here i have a problem like this ; i need to calculate the addition of that 2 cells and divide it with 60 an write it into right cell.

For example; i need to calculate addition of Mike FM IN and Mike FM OUT and i need to write it to Mike FM_HOUR cell.

How can i do that ?

i wrote this code but it doesnt work of course, just to help you ;

```
SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    string strSQL = "UPDATE bilgiler3 SET FM_HOUR= SELECT SUM((FM WHERE WORK_TYPE='OUT') + (FM WHERE WORK_TYPE='IN')) / 60 "
    string bag_str = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["asgdb01ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    conn = new SqlConnection(bag_str);
    conn.Open();...... and goes like this
```

Waiting your helps please.
I need to do that really.

Thank you very much.

Comment: are there any other columns aside from `NAME`,       `WORK_TYPE` ,       `FM`         ,   `FM_HOUR`?

Comment: Will there ever be multiple sets of in/out rows for the same user? What about when there is only an in (or only an out)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [sql-fiddle-demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9414/5) for a select using `sum() over` function. I *think* it supports sql-server 2005 and over.

I think you better do this in a stored procedure rather than inline sql.

For an *`UPDATE`* [sql-fiddle-demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57ad9/1)

```
update T1 set T1.fm_hour = T2.fm_hour
from T T1 join (Select distinct name,sum(fm) over (partition by name)/60 fm_hour
                from T) T2 on T1.name = T2.name
where T1.work_type = 'out'
```

For a *`SELECT`*

```
Select name,work_type,fm, 
       case work_type 
           when 'out' then sum(fm) over (partition by name)/60
           else null end fm_hour
from yourTable

| NAME | WORK_TYPE |    FM | FM_HOUR |
--------------------------------------
| Jane |        IN |   400 |  (null) |
| Jane |       OUT |  -100 |       5 |
| Mike |        IN | -2800 |  (null) |
| Mike |       OUT |  3400 |      10 |
```

Comment: In your `update` example, the `join` will return more than one row per name.  So your update might update a single row multiple times.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Bu (partition by name) what is this side ? what should i write there ?

Comment: That is for partition records by column [name] before summing. [name] is the name of column as per your given table

Answer (score 1):

this should produce the desired output :

```
UPDATE bilgiler3 SET FM_HOUR= T.Result
FROM (
  SELECT Name , SUM(FM) / 60 AS Result
  FROM bilgiler3
  GROUP BY Name
) T
INNER JOIN bilgiler3 ON T.Name = bilgiler3.Name
WHERE bilgiler3.Work_Type = 'OUT'
```